# Unable to creating room in XAMPPFramework(iOS), getting the error as remote-server-not-found with below code

Tags: ios, xmppframework, multiuserchat

```
XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"chat11@conference.local_IP"];
xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage jid:roomJID dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom activate:[self appDelegate].xmppStream];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"pandian"
 history:nil password:nil];
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the hostName and port number you have set for the XMPPStream object.

```
let stream = XMPPStream()
stream.hostName = "hostName"
stream.hostPort = PORT_NUM
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amruta now the delegate methods did create and did join gets call. but the newly created group not showing in openfire. can you please guide in this?.